# Wordpress encoded content to html

Tags: wordpress

I have to write a Wordpress WXR importer for a custom platform. Everything is working well except for iframe and embedded content.

When I export from Wordpress, I get embedded content as

```
YouTube[youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pY8jaGs7xJ0]
```

Instead of

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VH4VPjzT4O0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If it's just for youtube, I can manually write a parser, but I am not sure what kind of embeds I will run into.

How can I convert this Wordpress embed format to plain html ?

Note: I use Node.JS/Express and cannot use Wordpress functions.

Comment: this may be because of wordpress oembed feature https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds . If you import what you have exported into a wordpress site, iframe will be generated automatically. Otherwise you will have to write a parser to do that.

Comment: @Tamim I will be importing into a non-wordpress platform. So, I need html only output. I guess i have no option but to write a parser. Disappointed wordpress cannot output pure html. Why did they choose to go this route ??

Comment: Well, when writing a parser use the WordPress build in functions like do_shortcode for executing content shortcodes.